# How to use wp_category_checklist()?

Tags: categories, taxonomy, dropdown

I've recently discovered that we can insert a dropdown list of categories like this:

```
define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false );
require( './wp-load.php' );
wp_dropdown_categories( array(
    'child_of'         => 0,
    'class'            => 'postform', 
    'depth'            => 0,
    'echo'             => 1,
    'exclude'          => '', 
    'hide_empty'       => false, 
    'hide_if_empty'    => false,
    'hierarchical'     => true,
    'id'               => '',
    'name'             => 'cat-dropdown', 
    'order'            => 'ASC',
    'orderby'          => 'name', 
    'selected'         => 0, 
    'show_count'       => 0,
    'show_option_all'  => '', 
    'show_option_none' => __('None'),
    'tab_index'        => 0, 
    'taxonomy'         => 'format',
) );
```

This is great, BUT what if I want to select multiple categories?

I've come across `wp_category_checklist()` and tried this code:

```
function wp_category_checklist( 
    $post_id = 0, 
    $descendants_and_self = 0, 
    $selected_cats = false, 
    $popular_cats = false, 
    $walker = null, 
    $checked_ontop = true 
) {
    wp_terms_checklist( $post_id, array(
        'taxonomy'             => 'category',
        'descendants_and_self' => $descendants_and_self,
        'selected_cats'        => $selected_cats,
        'popular_cats'         => $popular_cats,
        'walker'               => $walker,
        'checked_ontop'        => $checked_ontop
    ) );
}
```

But it doesn't output anything.

I'm trying to get a list of my categories on a BLANK PAGE, not within a sidebar or post. Is that possible?

Comment: The code you wrote about `wp_category_checklist()` above is just the [function definition](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5/wp-admin/includes/template.php#L70).

Comment: Right, but wordpress' codex has absolutely no way to explain how to use it. Hence my question.

Comment: Unfortunately yes. But since it is based on [wp_terms_checklist()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_terms_checklist), you can have a look at the latter to see how it works.

Comment: but wp_terms_checklist is included in the function and that by itself also does not work. The codex also has nothing to explain how to use that function either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the answer I ended up with:

```
$select_cats = wp_dropdown_categories( array( 'echo' => 0 ) );
$select_cats = str_replace( "name='cat' id=", "name='cat[]' multiple='multiple' id=", $select_cats );
echo $select_cats;
```

It displays a list of my categories that can be multi-selected as per my question. It's a hack of `wp_dropdown_categories`, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

The function `wp_terms_checklist` is defined in the file `/wp-admin/includes/template.php` and therefore only available on the admin side of Wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select multiple custom taxonomy with checkbox. You can use that code..

```
 $html .= wp_dropdown_categories( array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'taxonomy_name',
                        'hierarchical' => 0,

                    ) );


$html = str_replace( "form id=", "form multiple='multiple' id=", $html );
$html = str_replace( "select", "span", $html );
$html = str_replace( "option class=", "input type='checkbox' class=", $html );
$html = str_replace( "option", "", $html );
$html = str_replace( "</>", "<br/>", $html );

echo $html;
```

And Tf You want to select multiple categories with checkbox. You can use that code..

```
$html = wp_dropdown_categories( array( 'echo' => 0, 'hierarchical' => 0 ) ); // Your Query here

$html = str_replace( "form id=", "form multiple='multiple' id=", $html );
$html = str_replace( "select", "span", $html );
$html = str_replace( "option class=", "input type='checkbox' class=", $html );
$html = str_replace( "option", "", $html );
$html = str_replace( "</>", "<br/>", $html );

echo $html;
```

Comment: Additional:  
If you want to select multiple texonomy? It will output a checklist of multiple texonomy. You can select multiple texonomy

Comment: You posted your answer twice. Please delete one of them.